# Angular 7 - Upload file to server

Tags: angular

I´m trying to send input file to server. When input file has data return in console this

```
 FileList {0: File, length: 1}0: File {name: "8mn4p369li331.png", lastModified: 1567609045831, lastModifiedDate: Wed Sep 04 2019 16:57:25 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 9587062, …}length: 1__proto__: FileList
```

I try to put this in formData element like this but doesn´t work

```
  save(form: NgForm) {
       const formData: FormData = new FormData();
       formData.append('file', this.selectedFiles, this.fileName)
       form.value["file"] = formData;
}
```

So: What´s is the right way to upload file (in a form) to the server?

**UPDATE: onChange function**

```
  fileEvent(event:any){
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    this.fileName = this.selectedFiles[0].name;
    console.log(this.selectedFiles);

}
```

Comment: You updated your comment, but what is the conclusion? Perhaps you should create a minimal setup?

Comment: see this link that is complete :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497240/angular-passing-formdata-to-webapi-getting-null/57498685#57498685

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have the right file:

```
let formdata = new FormData();
formdata.set('file', file, "fileName");
```

I believe you can only set one file per variable...

Edit: My file variable is a Blob...

```
Blob {size: 3151, type: "application/pdf"}
```

Comment: Failed to execute 'set' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.    The parametmer 2 is  this.selectedFiles[0].name;

Comment: Do you need help with getting a blob?

Answer (score 0):

your save function should be

```
save(form: NgForm) {
   const formData: FormData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file', this.selectedFiles[0], this.fileName)
   form.value["file"] = formData;
}
```

Comment: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.

Comment: second parameter should be `this.selectedFiles.files[0]`

Comment: formData.set('file', this.selectedFiles, this.fileName);
    form.value["file"] = formData.get("file"); Works