# HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized" - Sending Image With Post Request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular8

I am sending file with post request, m getting -  "Unauthorized"
       upload.component.html. and  upload.component.ts code -

```
 <input id="file-input" type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" accept="image/*" capture="environment" />


httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  '',
    'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('access_token')
   })
  }

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
results:any;
fileChange(event) {
    const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList) {
        const file = fileList[0];

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('Policy_files', file, file.name);
        this.http.post(SERVER_URL, formData, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
          response => {
            console.log(response)
          } ,  (error) => {
            if(error){
              alert('Server Responded With An Error')
              console.log(error)
            }}
      );

    }
}
```

Update - HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized"

Comment: When are you getting: cannot read property of null?

Comment: @Shikhathakur after uploading file, m getting response from server - TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Comment: Does this error from server-side?

Comment: see the complete example of sending file to server :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497240/angular-passing-formdata-to-webapi-getting-null/57498685#57498685

Comment: @Ankur where you are checking length?

Comment: @Ankur -this error is from server side , I think in the backend you checking the length of file that file is null, It means you do not send file to server correctly

Comment: Okay, I was not sending access token, Not i fixed that, But getting new error - HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized"

Comment: Check your backend if it requires the Token type (such as Bearer ) for Authorization header

Comment: I checked back-end @dasunse, Authorization  is required but they haven't mentioned about Token type

Comment: @Ankur In your Headers change `Content-Type` to multipart/form-data

Comment: @dasunse, Yeah tried adding `Content-Type`, Same response

Comment: @Ankur is your token expired??? check it..

Comment: i was using Policy_files insted of policy_files, Now its working